# dynamic initialPage not working in PageController

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

This is my page view code :

```
late PageController pageController;
int pageInd = 0;

class DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageView extends StatefulWidget {
  int initialPage = 0;
  DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageView({super.key, required this.initialPage});

  @override
  State<DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageView> createState() =>
      _DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageViewState();
}

class _DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageViewState
    extends State<DetailedWorkoutScreenStatePageView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: widget.initialPage); // adding the index to PageController
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: PageView.builder(
      onPageChanged: (ind) {
        setState(() {
          pageInd = ind;
        });
      },
      itemCount: allBodyPartWorkouts.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, ind) {
        WorkoutModel data = allBodyPartWorkouts[ind];
        return DetailedWorkoutScreen(
          name: data.name,
          bodyPart: data.bodyPart,
          gifUrl: data.gifUrl,
          target: data.target,
          instructions: data.instructions,
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

The initialPage variable is getting the right index still the page view is showing the first page.
where did i get it wrong? I really don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned a controller to your `PageView`. Add `pageController` to the `controller` field like this:

```dart
PageView.builder(
  controller: pageController,
  ...
)
```